# How to connect to blob container using SAS url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

i want to connect straight to container not to storage account using container's url with SAS.

For now i have code that work:

```
private async getContainer() {   
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(this.props.sasToken);
    let baseContainer = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(this.props.containerName);
    this.setState(state => ({ ...state, container: baseContainer }));
};
```

But in property `this.props.sasToken` i need to pass url to `Storage account` and container name.

Is it possible to connect to `container` using url with SAS only for this container? In [Azure Storage Explorer](https://www.sqltreeo.com/docs/connect-to-azure-blob-container-with-shared-access-signature-sas) it is possible but how to manage the same result programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [`ContainerClient(string, PipelineLike)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-containerclient-constructor-2) constructor to create an instance of `ContainerClient`. You will pass the container SAS URL as the first parameter.

Your code would be something like:

```
let baseContainer = new ContainerClient(this.props.sasToken);
this.setState(state => ({ ...state, container: baseContainer }));
```